# Unity Rigidbody click to move issue

Tags: c#, unity, movement, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm wanting to have a script that when I click in my scene, my player will rotate and have a force added to it and will travel until it has reached the clicked point in my scene.

Right now I have it working using Vectors and having my player lerp from one point to another. But I want to amend it so I can use physics and get a better sense of my player moving. Like have him speed up to start moving and slowing down as he reaches my target loction

My script now looks like this

```
public GameObject isActive;
public float speed;
public Ray ray;
public Rigidbody rigidBody;



public Vector3 targetPoint;
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    targetPoint = transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{


}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
    {
        targetPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        ChangeRotationTarget ();
    }

    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (targetPoint - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    rigidbody.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPoint, speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}


void ChangeRotationTarget ()
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane playerPlane = new Plane (Vector3.up, transform.position);

    float hitdist = 0.0f;

    if (playerPlane.Raycast (ray, out hitdist))
    {

        targetPoint = ray.GetPoint (hitdist);
    }

}
```

However, when I run this, he just slides from one point to another. Regardless of the drag or mass I put in my rigidbody.

Can someone help me make my changes? Or point me in the right direction

Comment: Have you considered using iTween?
http://itween.pixelplacement.com/index.php You can then use EaseTypes to get that acceleration then slowing down effect.

Comment: The problem is you're just changing the position of the rigidbody. If you want the physics engine to handle things (like using drag and mass). You need to change the velocity of the rigidbody, not the position. The physics engine is in charge of updating the position. You should look in to 'steering behaviors' and 'boids' to learn more about this type of functionality.